# browser/ngular does not send back my cookie to the server

Tags: angular, cookies, cors

I am doing my angular app(MEAN stack). On my server side I did all cors, I receve my cookie on the browser, but don't receive it back to the server to be able to identify the user. I just saw a post where someone had exact same problem except that there was a mixed up of localhost

- "the domain is not the same: localhost:3000 vs. 127.0.0.1:3000. Even though they point to the same destination, cookies are separated between both domains" and this was the reason the person did not have the cookie

My response and request both have localhost:3000, also on the interceptor in Angular when cloning the request I set the second property withCredentials: true.
(I check every request with postman and my cookie appear (console.log(cookie)) on each request, all works fine, not on Angular though, it is undefined.)

I have been struggling with that for few days trying to solve this but it just does not work. Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you

in Angular when cloning the request I set the second property withCredentials: true.to be able to receive the cookie with every request
On my server side I did all cors

```
 app.use((req, res, next) => {
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'HEAD, OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Cookie'); 
        next();
    })
```

also used the corse library, but it works same way

Comment: How are you setting the cookie in question? Show the relevant server code.

Comment: this is for log in and register: res.cookie("token-name", token, {
      httpOnly: true,
    });
i use jwt
Is this what you wanted to see or something else as well?

Comment: Add details in your question, not in comments. You should also add the relevant client code. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask